# Textbox data saved to database but dropdown box data didn't

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I custom form designed HTML and its working fine with Yii2 but only the data within textboxes is going into database and data within dropdown boxes doesn't go into database.

**Sample code:**

```
<form id="form-signup" action="/frontend/web/index.php?r=site%2Fsignup" method="post" role="form">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFirstName" name="SignupForm[firstName]" placeholder="Type First Name">

    <select onchange="getCountList(this.value)" id="inpCountry" name="SignupForm[region]" class="gwt-ListBox stdTextWidth">
                            <option value="">Select Region</option>
                            <option value="1">Australia and the Pacific</option>
                            <option value="2">Africa</option>
                            <option value="51">Asia</option>
                            <option value="3">Europe</option>
                            <option value="4">North America</option>
                            <option value="5">South America</option>
                          </select>
    </form>
```

When I submit the form the first name goes into database but the region id doesn't go into database.

**My Model:**

```
public function signup()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            $user = new User();
            $user->FirstName = $this->firstName;
            $user->UserRegionID = $this->region;
            if ($user->save()) {
                return $user;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

In debugger I can see data is being submitted by the form but its not saving in database.

```
[
    'firstName' => 'Pen'
    'region' => '1'
]
```

My table name is User and my fields are `FirstName` and `UserRegionID`

Comment: Show model validation rules.

Comment: @arogachev - I didn't create any validation rules for that dropdown box and in debugger I can see data is passing but not storing in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to validate some model attributes, in order to massively assign them, you need at least explicitly mark them as **safe**:

```
public function rules()
{
    ['UserRegionID', 'safe'],
}
```

Please read these official documentation sections to better understand validation:

- [Massive assignment](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#massive-assignment)
- [Safe attributes](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#safe-attributes)
- [Validating input](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html)